# How does "user = users(:michael)" work in Michael Hartl's Rails tutorial?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I don't understand how:    user = users(:michael)

works, for instance in Listing 12.12 here: https://www.railstutorial.org/book/password_reset

Does this have something to do with the .yml file? What is this method of creating users called?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These are called [Fixtures](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/testing.html#the-low-down-on-fixtures), and come from the `test/fixtures` directory within that application. Rails loads in some helpers which will define methods that match the name of the files defined in that directory.

When you do `users(:michael)`, it will read the data in that file underneath the `:michael` key and use that data to create a new user, using a call such as `User.create(data)`. You can see the data that would be used here back on [Listing 11.5](https://www.railstutorial.org/book/_single-page#code-fixture_users_activated).